# Can't find the site url

Tags: sharepoint-addin, url, spcontext

I am developing a sharepoint app (add-in) but I'm pretty new to sharepoint over all and need some help.

Asume that I am hosting the app on app-(app_id).sharepointapp.com and from that app I want to call a function or something which returns sharepoint.com which is the actual site (might be called test-site or something like that).

I have been trying to use `_spPageContextInfo` but I can't find a good match.

PS: Sorry if I've completely battered the SharePoint terminology.

[image]

Comment: Is that a SharePoint hosted app or provider hosted app? Also provide your code that you are trying...

Comment: It is a Sharepoint hosted app

Comment: So I've added the code in a image above. Above the ajax call I'm just trying a bunch of stuff. I've also found some stuff while searching and it looks like I should be trying to get the SPHostUrl.

Comment: try this url --> var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items"

Comment: The problem is that the _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl returns app-(randomid).sharepointapp.com and I want sharepoint.com, or at least that is what I think i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below methods you will get **SPHostUrl** and **SPAppWebUrl**. In hostweb you will get your "sharepoint.com" url.

```
// read URL parameters
function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
  var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&amp;");
  var strParams = "";
  for (var i = 0; i &lt; params.length; i = i + 1) {
    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == param) {
      return singleParam[1];
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // get the URLs of the host web and the app web
  SPAppWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
  SPHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
});
```

You can take reference from this [link](http://blog.ch.atosconsulting.com/performing-rest-operations-on-host-webs-from-sharepoint-hosted-apps/).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, This solved the problem splendidly!

Comment: Please upvote my answer....glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`SP.PageContextInfo.get_siteAbsoluteUrl()`, will give you the Site Collection URL.

`SP.PageContextInfo.get_webAbsoluteUrl()`, will give you the Site (or subsite) URL.